# Timeout exceeded in python

Tags: python, queue

### Task about queue in python

I was given a task at the institute, and I completed it. But when I started to conduct tests on the university platform, it gave me an error. Here is the condition:

> Queue task. Implement a
> queue using just an array. Data input and output is carried out
> through files. The names of the input and output files are specified
> through the command line arguments (the first and second,
> respectively). Input data format The input file contains a sequence of
> commands. Blank lines are ignored. The first line always contains
> "set_size N", where N is the maximum queue size, an integer. Each
> subsequent line contains exactly one command: push X, pop or print,
> where X is an arbitrary string without spaces.
>
> Result format The print command prints the contents of the queue (from
> head to tail) on one line, separated by spaces. If the queue is empty,
> "empty" is output. If the queue is full, "overflow" is output. The pop
> command displays the item or "underflow" if the queue is empty. Memory
> for the queue must be allocated no more than once when calling the
> "set_size" command. In any incomprehensible situation, the result of
> any command will be "error".

```
import sys
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.queue = []
        self.size = size
    def push(self, value):
        if len(self.queue) < self.size:
            return self.queue.append(value)
        else:
            return 'overflow'
    def pop(self):
        if self.queue:
            first = self.queue[0]
            del self.queue[0]
            return first
        else:
            return 'underflow'
    def print(self):
        global text
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            for i, element in enumerate(self.queue):
                if i + 1 < len(self.queue):
                    text += element + ' '
                else:
                    text += element
        else:
            text += 'empty'
        text += '\n'
        return
names = []
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for args in sys.argv[1:]:
        names.append(args)
in_file = names[0]
out_file = names[1]
f = open(in_file)
defined = False
text = ''
for i in f:
    com = i.strip('\n')
    if com.split(' ')[0] == 'set_size' and not defined:
        size = int(com.split(' ')[1])
        q = Queue(size)
        defined = True
    elif com == 'pop' and defined:
        text += q.pop() + '\n'
    elif com.split(' ')[0] == 'push' and len(com.split(' ')) == 2 and defined:
        value = com.split(' ')[1]
        pt = q.push(value)
        if pt is not None:
            text += pt + '\n'
    elif com == 'print' and defined:
        q.print()
    elif com == '':
        continue
    else:
        text += 'error\n'
f.close()
f = open(out_file, 'w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

When I uploaded to the testing platform on test 13, I received an error due to exceeded processing time
[image]

---

Here is the git where the file that was submitted in this receive test was uploaded, and the file that should have been, but my program was forcibly stopped by the testing platform itself, due to exceeding the processing time
https://github.com/RoyalGoose/testrepos

---

What could be the problem? How can I edit the code to make it work faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented in this form. In the end, the platform accepted the result

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, file_in, file_out):
        self.size = None
        self.queue = []
        self.file_in = file_in
        self.file_out = file_out
        return

    def set_size(self, size):
        try:
            assert self.size is None
        finally:
            self.size = int(size)
            self.queue.clear()

    def push(self, value):
        self.queue.append(value if len(self.queue) < self.size else 'overflow')

    def pop(self):
        return (self.queue.pop(0) if self.queue else 'underflow') + '\n'

    def print(self):
        return (' '.join(self.queue) if self.queue else 'empty') + '\n'

    def work(self):
        with open(self.file_in) as f, open(self.file_out, 'w') as f2:
            fr = filter(bool, map(str.rstrip, f))
            for line in fr:
                try:
                    try:
                        (cmd, arg) = line.split(' ', 1)
                    except ValueError:
                        f2.write(getattr(self, line)())
                    except Exception:
                        raise
                    else:
                        getattr(self, cmd)(arg)
                except Exception as e:
                    f2.write('error\n')
                continue
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue('input', 'outfile')
    q.work()
```